# Kindle-optimized IMAP Webmail Client

Tags: imap, kindle, webmail

I recently bought a Kindle 3G which comes with a simple Webkit-based web browser. This would be the perfect device to check my email abroad (because of the free 3G worldwide) but unfortunately I have yet to find a webmail client that actually works well with the limited resources and the small eInk display. For example it doesn't play well with Squirrelmail or Roundcube and even Gmail doesn't work too well.

Is anybody aware of webmail software that works well with Kindle and let's me connect to arbitrary IMAP servers? If this doesn't exist yet and there is some interest I might also write such a client myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try Horde Webmail (http://www.horde.org). It offers a "Minimal" view optimized for smartphone views and a "Smartphone" view based on jQuery Mobile. The latter is supposed to support the Kindle 3 and Kindle Fire (see http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/). I did not test Kindle support myself though.